# efficient way to transfer data in s3

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-s3, boto

I have 5 billion + keys to copy from one region to another.  Currently, I'm threading and multiprocessing but the results that I'm getting are a little slow for my needs. I'm getting anywhere from 8 seconds to almost 2 minuets (average about 50 seconds) for a 1000 `PUT` copy requests.  This will take close to a year to complete.

Does anyone know of a faster way of going about this?  I was reading about python's [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html) module and it looks promising but it's rather confusing to me.  How can I integrate boto with asyncore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the API can be quite inefficient when a lot of requests are required.

HTTP overhead plays a big role here.
Throwing 5 bil COPY requests against the API will take a while, waiting for each response in a traditional way would take ages (as you said, years) even with threading because each request blocks one thread.

So your idea to use non-blocking asynchronous connections is a great start.

I am not a great python developer unfortunately so I can't really help you with the replacement of the underlying http client in boto.

[This guys](https://github.com/yyuu/botornado) did this already, (quick and dirty, they say) using the [tornado.httpclient](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html)

Maybe you can use this to get an idea of how to implement asyncore

Answer (score 1):

Using asyncore might help a bit but I don't think the end result will be that much faster than a threaded solution.  If I had 5 billion objects to move in S3, I would find a way to split that work up among as many EC2 instances as I could afford.  The difficult part is finding a way to split work up among the worker instances.

- You could gather a list of all the objects in the bucket using `list_keys` and then queue up messages in SQS for each object that needs to be moved.  Then fire up N EC2 instances all reading from the same queue.  However, even listing the keys would take a long time and then queueing up 5 billion messages would take a while, also.
- If the objects are naturally partitioned on S3 you could take advantage of that.  For example, if there is a pseudo-hierarchy you could start each of the instances off with a different `prefix`.
- If you have the object names stored in a separate database, you could generate N separate files of object keys and pass one file to each of the N EC2 instances.

There may be other possibilities.  It's hard to know without more details about your specific situation.  However, I think you need to find some way to spread the work out among EC2 instances if you want to get this done in a reasonable amount of time.